# Action listener is not working on certain buttons

Tags: java, swing

I have problem making actionlistener work on certain buttons after I "restart" my map. The thing is btns[1] to btns[9] do not work at all ! It might be some problem with my variables, I am not sure. I tried everything. These buttons are simply not working after I start new Map (After I press button btns[0] .. New Map ). Here is my code, hope you help me guys. New Board(null) - if there's null in constructor, it is supposed to create blanket map, which I have coded in constructor of Board class(I guess it doesn't really matter, because it is working first time I launch the new Game(null) ).

If you find it impossible to find out why it is not working, I uploaded my whole game to sendspace = http://www.sendspace.com/file/pvwtoo - Jar form,  http://www.sendspace.com/file/l18khb - BlueJ form - for better coordination if necessary. Thanks a lot in advance for all your help. 
Luke

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
Board b;
Menu m;
Container c = getContentPane();
JPanel pnl;
ImageIcon ii;
JLabel jl;
JTextArea jt;
private JButton [] btns = new JButton[10];
String selectMore = "Select more = false";
int posx,posy;

public Game(Map m) {
    createGui(m);
}

public void createGui(Map mm)
{
    b = new Board(mm);
    //m = new Menu();
    c.add(b);

    pnl = new JPanel();
    ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("menu.png"));
    pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(16,10));
    pnl.setSize(100,608);
    //pnl.add(m);
    pnl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    c.add(pnl,BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    setTitle("Strgame");
    c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);  

    //this.pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(800, 608);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);

    //setUndecorated(true); 
    //setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 

    setVisible(true);


    manageButtons();
    infoPanel();
    pnl.requestFocusInWindow();
    requestFocusInWindow();
}

public void manageButtons()
{
    if(pnl!=null){pnl.removeAll();}
    btns[0] = new JButton("New Map");
    btns[1] = new JButton("Change XY to House 1");
    btns[2] = new JButton("Change XY to House 2");
    btns[3] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 1");
    btns[4] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 2");
    btns[5] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 3");
    btns[6] = new JButton("Change XY to Grass");
    btns[7] = new JButton("Get info of selected");
    btns[9] = new JButton(selectMore);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(btns[i] != null)
        {
            btns[i].addActionListener(this);
            btns[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(213,10));
            btns[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            btns[i].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            pnl.add(btns[i]);
        }
    }
}

public void infoPanel()
{
    jl = new JLabel("Info");
    jl.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
    jl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    pnl.add(jl);        
    jt = new JTextArea();
    //jt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(211,10));
    //jt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
    jt.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    //jt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jt.setMargin(new Insets(2,2,2,2));
    jt.setEditable(false);
    jt.setText(" Not selected");
    pnl.add(jt);
}


public int posx()
{
    int [] pom = b.lastPosSelected(); 
    posx = pom[0];        
    return posx;
}

public int posy()
{
    int [] pom = b.lastPosSelected();   
    posy = pom[1];        
    return posy;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    String action = e.getActionCommand();  
    if(action.equals("New Map"))
    {
        createGui(null);
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to House 1"))
    {
        b.changexy("house");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to House 2"))
    {
        b.changexy("house1");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to Road 1"))
    {
        b.changexy("road");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to Road 2"))
    {
        b.changexy("road1");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to Road 3"))
    {
        b.changexy("road2");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Change XY to Grass"))
    {
        b.changexy("grass");
        b.revalidate();
        b.repaint();
        c.repaint();
    }
    else if(action.equals("Select more = false"))
    {
        b.selMore();
        b.repaint();
        selectMore = "Select more = true";
        btns[9].setText(selectMore);
    }
    else if(action.equals("Select more = true"))
    {
        b.selMore();
        b.repaint();
        selectMore = "Select more = false";
        btns[9].setText(selectMore);
    }
    else if(action.equals("Get info of selected"))
    {
        jt.setText(" Name: "+b.getSelected()+"\n Costs: "+b.getSelectedCost());
    }
}    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game(null);
}

}
```

Comment: I was just walking through various comments posted by you, and then came across this `ActionListener` thingy you were referring to. Well for that matter, you can have a look at various approaches you can take for attaching an ActionListener : [__First Approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nfyly2anqmo7v87/Skeleton.java), [__Second Approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cso39hh1efpcls/Skeleton1.java), [__Third Approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3dhwdbfxmcvpsng/Skeleton2.java) and [__Fourth Approach__](https://www.dropbox.com/s/671hqa629pbi95u/Skeleton3.java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "action command" of a button is not necessarily the text of the button.  Try replacing the test for the text with

`if (e.getSource() == button[1])`

or similar to have a reliable test. If that worked at all, it was more likely luck - there's nothing in the spec to suggest that the button text will be the action command, and in fact if you use a `javax.swing.Action`, it usually will not be.

There are a number of other problems with this code that make it more difficult to read and predict what it does:

- If testing a string constant, always use the form `"THE CONSTANT".equals(something)` since you can guarantee that the constant is not null;  the other way around is a null pointer exception.

  - In this case, if you were keeping the test code, you could use switch-over-strings
- You do a null check on pnl, and then later try to assign it.  In fact it will not be null.  Move the initialization code to the constructor, getting rid of `createGui`, and make the Pnl field final. Then the code is simpler and you enlist the compiler to *prove* pnl cannot be null, eliminating that entire category of bug from the realm of possibility.
- When reconstructing the GUI, if you remove and add components at runtime, you need the `invalidate(); revalidate(); repaint();` incantation to make sure the display is updated - whether the code here works or not will vary by JDK and look and feel.  And actually, you don't need to reconstruct the GUI at all.

Comment: Well, my teacher taught me to use action listener for buttons that way = I am therefore sorry for posting such trivial issue hure. Thanks for your time and suggestions. Now I am going to get all over your post once again and try to understand all the points you mentioned. Luke

Answer (score 5):

I think that you'll be far better off not creating a new GUI in an almost recursive fashion when resetting program state but instead changing the current displayed GUI to its initial state. This is likely where your problem is.

In other words, I'd change this:

```
  if (action.equals("New Map")) {
     createGui(null);
     b.revalidate();
     b.repaint();
     c.repaint();
  }
```

to this:

```
  if (action.equals("New Map")) {
     b.reset();
  }
```

And of course would give the Board class a `reset()` method where it resets its state and display.

For more help, post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), not links to a large complex GUI.

---

Edit, my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
   Board b;
   Menu m;
   Container c = getContentPane();
   JPanel pnl;
   JLabel jl;
   JTextArea jt;
   private JButton[] btns = new JButton[10];
   String selectMore = "Select more = false";
   int posx, posy;

   public Game(Map m) {
      createGui(m);
   }

   public void createGui(Map mm) {
      b = new Board(mm);
      c.add(b);

      pnl = new JPanel();
      pnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 10));
      pnl.setSize(100, 608);
      pnl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      c.add(pnl, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

      setTitle("Strgame");
      c.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(800, 608);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);

      setVisible(true);

      manageButtons();
      infoPanel();
      pnl.requestFocusInWindow();
      requestFocusInWindow();
   }

   public void manageButtons() {
      if (pnl != null) {
         pnl.removeAll();
      }
      btns[0] = new JButton("New Map");
      btns[1] = new JButton("Change XY to House 1");
      System.out.println("btns[1] hash: " + btns[1].hashCode());
      btns[2] = new JButton("Change XY to House 2");
      btns[3] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 1");
      btns[4] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 2");
      btns[5] = new JButton("Change XY to Road 3");
      btns[6] = new JButton("Change XY to Grass");
      btns[7] = new JButton("Get info of selected");
      btns[9] = new JButton(selectMore);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         if (btns[i] != null) {
            btns[i].addActionListener(this);
            btns[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(213, 10));
            btns[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
            btns[i].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
            pnl.add(btns[i]);
         }
      }
   }

   public void infoPanel() {
      jl = new JLabel("Info");
      jl.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
      jl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
      pnl.add(jl);
      jt = new JTextArea();
      jt.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
      jt.setMargin(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
      jt.setEditable(false);
      jt.setText(" Not selected");
      pnl.add(jt);
   }

   public int posx() {
      int[] pom = b.lastPosSelected();
      posx = pom[0];
      return posx;
   }

   public int posy() {
      int[] pom = b.lastPosSelected();
      posy = pom[1];
      return posy;
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      Object source = e.getSource();
      System.out.println("source hash: " + source.hashCode());

      String action = e.getActionCommand();
      if (action.equals("New Map")) {
         createGui(null);
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to House 1")) {
         b.changexy("house");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to House 2")) {
         b.changexy("house1");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to Road 1")) {
         b.changexy("road");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to Road 2")) {
         b.changexy("road1");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to Road 3")) {
         b.changexy("road2");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Change XY to Grass")) {
         b.changexy("grass");
         b.revalidate();
         b.repaint();
         c.repaint();
      } else if (action.equals("Select more = false")) {
         b.selMore();
         b.repaint();
         selectMore = "Select more = true";
         btns[9].setText(selectMore);
      } else if (action.equals("Select more = true")) {
         b.selMore();
         b.repaint();
         selectMore = "Select more = false";
         btns[9].setText(selectMore);
      } else if (action.equals("Get info of selected")) {
         jt.setText(" Name: " + b.getSelected() + "\n Costs: "
               + b.getSelectedCost());
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Game(null);
   }

}

class Board extends JPanel {

   private Map map;
   private JLabel xyLabel = new JLabel("    ");

   public Board(Map map) {
      this.map = map;
      add(xyLabel);

   }

   public String getSelectedCost() {
      return "getSelectedCose";
   }

   public String getSelected() {
      return "getSelected";
   }

   public void selMore() {

   }

   public void changexy(String xy) {
      xyLabel.setText(xy);
   }

   public int[] lastPosSelected() {

      return new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   }

}

class Map {

}
```

If you run this, you'll see from the hashcodes printed that your gui is getting response from the first set of buttons created, not the second set, and this is why your GUI doesn't work.

For instance, my output looked like this:

```
btns[1] hash: 17514905
source hash: 17514905
source hash: 17514905
source hash: 12934710
btns[1] hash: 23063136
source hash: 17514905
```

Again, this can all be solved if you follow my initial advice: ***reset*** your Board, don't replace it, and certainly don't replace all the menu buttons.

Also you will want to `pack()` your GUI after setting it up, and not set sizes of anything.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My way of reseting was kind of stupid. I actualy reset whole gui instead of just reseting array list(containing my map), which is less effective way of doing that. Also, as I mentioned before I was taught at school to use action listener that way, which doesn't seem to be the best way of doing so. I have to take my time and get all over it again. Thanks for your time, I appriciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Nice program by the way fun clicking around it. You have a couple weird things going on in this program that I think you could improve on and it would solve this problem as well as make your application run better.

1. Once you add everything to your UI its not best practice to be removing everything and re add it, there are some exceptions but shy away from it if possible. It is resource inefficient and you can end up with weird problems like the one your facing due to multiple instances of objects lingering around in the GUI thread.
2. As hovercraft stated previously you should create a method called clearBoard or clearMap inside your board class that will erase the map, then call that when you want a new map.
3. I implemented this in your code and got everything working but I noticed some strange discrepancies in what classes contain what. When I added the clearBoard method to the Board class and clearMap to the map Map class I initally just re-initiallized a the map[][] variable. But something stranged happened! the icons never disappeared from the board but clicking on the button "Get info of selected" returned that it was a grass node when it was not. You have 2 arrays actually going on here, one containing images in the Board class and one in the Map class. You should move the images out of the board class and into the map class. My suggestion, remove the array Image[][] images from the Board and only leave one 2d array containing map data, then get your images when you draw that map.

If you would like to see what I changed I can upload your altered source.

-Best

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. You are right, I got that idea of reseting only the map already. Have to take some time and implement reset method. And of course you can post your code edit, I would love to see your code ! Luke

Comment: I was bored last night and I made more edits that I really should have but heres a link to the source. http://ftp-ns-drop.com/stack/strgame.zip

Comment: Wow ! I can see the practical use of enum type of the class for the first time and it looks amazing ! Thank you very much for this. Would you mind if I used some of your code ? I am pretty new to java but I kind of fel in love with it :3.

Comment: Yea of course, glad you like the enum. Its good to get used to using enums for cases like this were you have static data types. It makes your code very clear and readable for others (very important in the future). Let me know if you have any question about what I wrote ill be glad to answer them.

Comment: Very nice from you to let me use it also thanks for making this clear for me about enum. There is one thing I would like to ask though. I am not really sure what the method registerResouces() in the class Board does. Can you tell me more about how your HashMap works in that kind of case (honestly, didn't have a chance to work with that kind of arraylist so far)? Thanks, Luke.

Comment: The function registerResouces loads all the Images we need for the game and loads them into a Hashmap. This allows our images to only be loaded 1 time, when we need to find a resource we call tiles.get(Unit.getSystemName()) and it will return the Image associated with that resource. Im going to simplify what a hashmap is and how it works but the crux of it is a hashmap is a data structure in which each entry consists of 1 key and a corresponding value. The hashmap can only contain one value per key, in this case the key is defined by a String Unit.getSystemName() and the Image.

Comment: Oh, I totally get this line now:    g2d.drawImage(tiles.get(Unit.GRASS.getSystemName()), 29 * i, 29 * j, null); Thank you very much for your time helping me, I really appriciate it. Now I can move on creating my game :).